# Jackal odometry producing large covariances?

Tags: navigation, ekf, odometry, ros-kinetic, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting exploding covariance readings (along the diagonal) when echoing my /odometry/filtered topic on a jackal robot

```
header:    seq: 51936   stamp: 
    secs: 1533236107
    nsecs: 579915762   frame_id: "odom" child_frame_id: "base_link" pose:    pose: 
    position: 
      x: -1.0615022635
      y: 0.781039664382
      z: 0.0574243827245
    orientation: 
      x: -0.000565326105048
      y: 0.00129452020895
      z: -0.722981516966
      w: 0.690865928201   covariance: [52.22660058406395,
2.36797290728725e-06, 1.0344690435191654e-05, -1.412923508928883e-37, -5.323328075794997e-37, -3.0325742350059946e-33, 2.3679729072872455e-06, 52.226580153537775, 4.630394046333056e-06, 6.415510432550216e-39, -1.52209745995386e-35, 1.378174221195611e-34, 1.0344690435191593e-05, 4.630394046333093e-06, 62.66584761441557, 2.4284539729416056e-39, 6.071418793042712e-33, -5.009970111481826e-38, -1.4129235089288823e-37, 6.415510432550213e-39, 2.4284539729415573e-39, 9.999974359129776e-10, 3.7247437261868537e-28, -2.646392184397966e-26, -5.323328075794997e-37, -1.5220974599538599e-35, 6.071418793042711e-33, 3.7247437261815377e-28, 9.999974359129776e-10, -1.0056936786572167e-25, -3.0325742350059946e-33, 1.3781742211956115e-34, -5.009970111481829e-38, -2.6463921843979677e-26, -1.0056936786572173e-25, 9.999987179531678e-10] twist:    twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -1.36494277252e-16
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.00114722208953
      y: -0.000894948616335
      z: -0.000156898909114   covariance: [0.0015009578520837957,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0015009578520837957, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0020931884517782426, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.21732790378605e-07, 8.251167061986038e-27, -4.2753698250399015e-24, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.251167062032128e-27, 1.21732790378605e-07, -1.3789888806793583e-24, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.275369825039899e-24, -1.3789888806793574e-24, 1.2178973261379077e-07].
```

What are ways of mitigating this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299475/jackal-odometry-producing-large-covariances?/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-02**:
Can you please repost the output using the `101010` button to enable formatting vs using the `"` button (which is meant for quoting things)? It's difficult to read the output as is.

**Comment by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on 2018-08-02**:
Done. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the `/odometry/filtered` topic is being published by an instance of `robot_localization`. It is likely set up to fuse wheel velocities and measurements from the internal IMU (orientation). This means the EKF has no absolute x/y/z measurements, so it is expected that the covariance would increase over time. You'd need to fuse absolute x/y/z measurements into the EKF if you didn't want the covariance to explode.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on 2018-08-02**:
Okay, how do I do that? Are you saying to use wifi or GPS? Also, my covariances explodes with **very little** movement, especially for the angular measurements. It basically starts out extremely uncertain and remains that way.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-08-03**:
You can also feed it a pose from some sort of localization node, e.g., `amcl`. You are integrating velocities, so you will integrate their errors, too.

When the robot rotates, the linear covariances will grow much faster once the robot starts translating again. This is normal.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-08-03**:
If you don't like the growth rate in the covariance, you can (a) decrease the covariance coming from your wheel encoders, and/or (b) decrease the `process_noise_covariance` for the robot's pose and velocity variables.

**Comment by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on 2018-08-03**:
Are you saying I can just arbitrarily set to the encoder covariances and process_noise-covariance to what whatever I want? How would this reflect the actual uncertainty from those nodes?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-08-05**:
Yes, you can. And it depends on your robot and your application. I am not familiar with how the wheel odom covariance was generted for the Jackal, nor how they tuned the process noise, but I'd be willing to bet that you can adjust the latter until you feel the covariance growth is realistic.